# Replacing text with images using jQuery , simplied way possible?

Tags: jquery

I am using this script to replace some user names with their corresponding icons. The host site gives a parameter for each user name and icon ranging from fid_0000  to fid_0099 , but their html currently only places the icons on certain reports , so in order to have them show on an additional report I've called out the table and used jQuery to replace them.

This is working fine below, however it only replaces the fid_0000 with its corresponding icon. How can i make it so any fid , ranging from fid_0000 < is replaced , as the first user is marked fid_0000 along with their icons - so i'd need it to range from there to infinite

```
$( "table#brief_standings" ).html( $( "table#brief_standings" ).html().replace(franchiseDatabase['fid_0000'].name, '<img src="' + franchiseDatabase['fid_0000'].icon + '" />') );
```

fid_0000 , fid_0001 , fid_0003..  ..  .. .. fid_0096  , is the range i need

Comment: i am very green in jQuery so by saying a "loop" you just lost me lol

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "[Loop](http://bit.ly/1zGPoXD)" is a general programming term and it applies to almost all languages. Whenever you see you're repeating something (not to mention repeating it 100 times), it means you're not doing it right.

Comment: There are more subtle problems in your current algorithm. For one, fetch the HTML markup from the DOM once, process it at your leisure, then update the DOM once, not on every iteration.

Comment: Frederic , example please ?

Comment: Looks at all these calls to `html()`. That's DOM access. Ideally you only want two calls to `html()` -- a getter and a setter, with your loop in-between. Otherwise, performance will drop tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $t = $( "table#brief_standings" ),
    x = franchiseDatabase,
    y = 'fid_00',
    z = $( "table#brief_standings" ).html();
for( i = 1; i<= 16; i++ ) {
    var j = (i < 10) ? y + '0' + i : y + i;
    z = z.replace( x[j].name, '<img src="' + x[j].icon + '" />' );
}
$t.html( z );
```

Comment: This is only working if i have 16 items replaced , if i have 17 it fails. How can i have 0-96 , regardless of how many between that value ?

Comment: @MShack `for( i = 1; i<= 16; i++ ) {` Change the `16` in this to whatever limit you want (less than `100`)

Comment: Thats the issue , the amount needed always changes. If i set it to 50 , but 51 is needed then 1 is left unchanged. If i set it to a high # , and less are needed , it fails completely

Comment: You can try using `x.length` instead of a number there.

Comment: I just updated my first post , maybe that is more clear i hope. The host sets a parameter for each user , the first one is fid_0000 and the range goes up from there. In example in edited post, that replaces only 1 user , so how can i set the range to infinite from that point ?